# pymssql how to passing output parameter

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I've tried using this code :

```
   outputparam1 = pymssql.output(int)
   outputparam2=pymssql.output(int)
   outputparam3=pymssql.output(int)

    try:
        with pymssql.connect('localhost','sa','anypassword', 'anydb') as conn:
            with conn.cursor(as_dict=True) as cursor:
                cursor.callproc("storedprocedure_name",('inputparam', outputparam1, outputparam2, outputparam3))
    except Exception,e:
        pass
```

and this is the SQL Server stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[storedprocedure_name]
     (@inputparam NVARCHAR(100),                                         
      @outputparam1 INT OUTPUT,
      @outputparam2 INT OUTPUT,
      @outputparam3 INT OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
END;
```

This codes still throws an exception

> Expected parameter @outputparam1..."

Any help would be very appreciate, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cursor.callproc('storedprocedure_name', (first_param, second_param, an_output_param,))
```

Then returned value will be available in the "an_output_param" variable.

In your case you should try this.

```
cursor.callproc("storedprocedure_name", ('inputparam', outputparam1, outputparam2, outputparam3,))
```

Try this as well

```
sqlcmd = """
DECLARE @outputparam1 INT, @outputparam2 INT, @outputparam3 INT

EXEC storedprocedure_name
     %s, @outputparam1 OUT, @outputparam2 OUT, @outputparam3 OUT

SELECT @outputparam1, @outputparam2, @outputparam3
"""
res = conn.execute_row(sqlcmd, ('inputparam'))
```

Comment: yes,this is what i tried,but throws error expect parameter @outputparam1...

Comment: "Procedure or function 'storeprocedure_name' expects parameter '@outputparam1', which was not supplied.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:
General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server
"